# Profit and loss using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe containing data like this:

```
                       open   close  signal
date_time                                                          
2011-01-03 01:04:00  1.5560  1.5556    0.0
2011-01-03 01:05:00  1.5557  1.5556    0.0
2011-01-03 01:06:00  1.5557  1.5556    1.0
2011-01-03 01:07:00  1.5556  1.5545    1.0
2011-01-03 01:08:00  1.5546  1.5548    1.0
2011-01-03 01:09:00  1.5549  1.5547    0.0
2011-01-03 01:10:00  1.5548  1.5549    0.0
2011-01-03 01:11:00  1.5549  1.5551    1.0
2011-01-03 01:12:00  1.5550  1.5552    1.0
2011-01-03 01:13:00  1.5553  1.5553    0.0
2011-01-03 01:14:00  1.5552  1.5553    0.0
```

Which is a fairly standard way of representing a financial timeseries in Python.

Now, I want to use the signal column to trade. When signal == 1 then buy, when it gets back to 0 then sell. The signal is known at the end of the current minute, so when we say 'Buy', it really means 'buy at the open of the next minute'.

Let's say the initial value of our portfolio is 1.0. I want a timeseries that outputs:

```
                       pnl
date_time                                                          
2011-01-03 01:04:00    1.0
2011-01-03 01:05:00    1.0
2011-01-03 01:06:00    1.0
2011-01-03 01:07:00    0.999292877 # Buy: pnl = (1.0 * 1.5545 / 1.5556)
2011-01-03 01:08:00    0.999485729 # Hold: pnl = (1.0 * 1.5548 / 1.5556)
2011-01-03 01:09:00    0.999421445 # Hold: pnl = (1.0 * 1.5547 / 1.5556)
2011-01-03 01:10:00    0.999485729 # Sell: pnl = (1.0 * 1.5548 / 1.5556)
2011-01-03 01:11:00    0.999485729 # Wait
2011-01-03 01:12:00    0.999614280 # Buy: pnl = (0.999485729 * 1.5552 / 1.5550)
2011-01-03 01:13:00    0.999678556 # Hold: pnl = (0.999485729 * 1.5553 / 1.5550)
2011-01-03 01:14:00    0.999614280 # Sell: pnl = (0.999485729 * 1.5552 / 1.5550)
2011-01-03 01:15:00    0.999614280 # Wait
```

Any idea how to do this with pandas **without looping through the dataframe?**

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the buy/sell hold (perhaps you have an error in your sell time?), but this should get you close as an idea.  The key is to compute an array 'units' that indicates if you are holding stock or not.  Then the rest should work OK.  Each day you either change value (.99 or 1.01, e.g. based on stock close price), or hold value (1.0).  The cumprod() function then accumulates those changes.  Since you are buying at the open, you will need to add some complexity.  You could create a 'buy' array like `signal[1:0]-signal[0:-1]` if you need to do something special at those times.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([[ 1.5560,  1.5556,    0.0],
                [ 1.5557,  1.5556,    0.0],
                [ 1.5557,  1.5556,    1.0],
                [ 1.5556,  1.5545,    1.0],
                [ 1.5546,  1.5548,    1.0],
                [ 1.5549,  1.5547,    0.0],
                [ 1.5548,  1.5549,    0.0],
                [ 1.5549,  1.5551,    1.0],
                [ 1.5550,  1.5552,    1.0],
                [ 1.5553,  1.5553,    0.0],
                 [ 1.5552,  1.5553,    0.0]], columns=['open','close','signal'])

#You will need to adjust units based on your exact buy/sell times.  Assuming here that
#units are signal delayed by 1 time slot.
units=np.insert(df['signal'].values,0,[0])[0:-1]
#change is relative change in price from day before.  Insert 1.0 in first day to represent start
change_close=np.insert(df['close'].values[1:]/df['close'].values[0:-1],0,[1])
#hold is 1,0 flag whether you are holding stock
hold=(units>0)
#relative change in value is either change_close or 1.0 (no change)
change_value=hold*change_close + ~hold*1.0
#cumulative product of changes gives current value
pnl=change_value.cumprod()
#insert back into dataframe as new column
df['pnl']=pnl
df

open   close  signal       pnl
0   1.5560  1.5556     0.0  1.000000
1   1.5557  1.5556     0.0  1.000000
2   1.5557  1.5556     1.0  1.000000
3   1.5556  1.5545     1.0  0.999293
4   1.5546  1.5548     1.0  0.999486
5   1.5549  1.5547     0.0  0.999421
6   1.5548  1.5549     0.0  0.999421
7   1.5549  1.5551     1.0  0.999421
8   1.5550  1.5552     1.0  0.999486
9   1.5553  1.5553     0.0  0.999550
10  1.5552  1.5553     0.0  0.999550
```

Perhaps if you posted  looping code that does what you want, it might be easier for someone to vectorize.